# elasticsearch-spark failing to index type after parent is set

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

I start of by manually setting the type via the rest API with the following command:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/myIndex/ -d '{
  "mappings" : { 
          "company": {}, 
          "people": {
               "_parent" : {
                   "type" : "company"
                }
           }
       }
}'
```

Yet, at the spark layer, with the following code

Here is the people mapping

```
object PeopleDataCleaner {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val liftedArgs = args.lift
    val mongoURL = liftedArgs(0).getOrElse("mongodb://127.0.0.1/mg_test.lc_data_test")
    val elasticsearchHost = liftedArgs(1).getOrElse("52.35.155.55")
    val elasticsearchPort = liftedArgs(2).getOrElse("9200")
    val mongoReadPreferences = liftedArgs(3).getOrElse("primary")
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Mongo Data CLeaner")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", mongoURL)
      .config("mongo.input.query", "{currentCompanies : {$exists: true, $ne: []}}")
      .config("mongo.readPreference.name", mongoReadPreferences)
      .config("es.nodes", elasticsearchHost)
      .config("es.port", elasticsearchPort)
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val data = MongoSpark.load[LCDataRecord](spark)
      .as[LCDataRecord]
      .filter { record =>
        record.currentCompanies != null &&
        record.currentCompanies.nonEmpty &&
        record.linkedinId != null
      }
      .map { record =>
        val moddedCurrentCompanies = record.currentCompanies
          .filter { currentCompany => currentCompany.link != null && currentCompany.link != "" }
        record.copy(currentCompanies = moddedCurrentCompanies)
      }
      .flatMap { record =>
          record.currentCompanies.map { currentCompany =>
            currentCompanyToFlatPerson(record, currentCompany)
          }
      }
      .saveToEs("myIndex/people", Map(
        "es.mapping.id" -> "idField",
        "es.mapping.parent" -> "companyLink"
      ))
  }
```

here is the company

```
object CompanyDataCleaner {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val liftedArgs = args.lift
    val mongoURL = liftedArgs(0).getOrElse("mongodb://127.0.0.1/mg_test.lc_data_test")
    val elasticsearchHost = liftedArgs(1).getOrElse("localhost")
    val elasticsearchPort = liftedArgs(2).getOrElse("9200")
    val mongoReadPreferences = liftedArgs(3).getOrElse("primary")
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Mongo Data CLeaner")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", mongoURL)
      .config("mongo.input.query", "{currentCompanies : {$exists: true, $ne: []}}")
      .config("mongo.readPreference.name", mongoReadPreferences)
      .config("es.index.auto.create", "true")
      .config("es.nodes", elasticsearchHost)
      .config("es.port", elasticsearchPort)
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val data = MongoSpark
      .load[LCDataRecord](spark)
      .as[LCDataRecord]
      .filter { record => record.currentCompanies != null && record.currentCompanies.nonEmpty }
      .flatMap(record => record.currentCompanies)
      .filter { record => record.link != null }
      .dropDuplicates("link")
      .map(formatCompanySizes)
      .map(companyToFlatCompany)
      .saveToEs("myIndex/company", Map("es.mapping.id" -> "link"))

  }
```

There is a failure message stating 
`org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured`. This is not an issue by first indexing the companies into elasticsearch, my understanding is that the above mapping should have defined the parent/child relationship.

**EDIT** Using the bulk API over REST or using the normal REST indexing API doesn't encounter this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `.config("es.index.auto.create", "true")` to `.config("es.index.auto.create", "false")` fixes the problem for me. It appears that even though the index and type exist, EsSpark is still trying to create it, and if it has a `parent` field set thats not a legal operation.